# What is the proper way to charge Lithium Ion batteries?

Tags: power, battery, lifetime

Lithium Ion Batteries are becoming more and more popular in spacecraft, due to their high power per mass ratio. There are several companies, such as [Quallion](http://www.quallion.com/sub-ms-satellites.asp), advertising their space rated batteries. What is the proper way to charge them to optimize battery life, and prevent fires such as occurred in the Boeing 787 Dreamliner?

For example, [the ISS](http://spaceflightnow.com/news/n1304/30issbattery/#.UikOi3-NPfM) is planning on launching them in 2016, as are several other missions I am aware of.

Comment: What are some spacecraft that use them?

Comment: Seems almost better for Physics or Chem

Answer (score 3):

Although this question belongs to physics or chemistry still following is the answer you are looking for.

> The  typical charging protocol for the Li-Ion cells with layered
>   cathodes includes a constant current  charge to a voltage of 3.9 V to
>   4.2 V (depending on the metal oxide cathode and manufacturer’s  recommendations) and held at constant voltage until the current falls
>   down to approximately  C/50 or C/100 (this can vary according to the
>   manufacturer).  The term, “C” signifies the charge  or discharge rate,
>   in Amperes, expressed as a multiple of the rated capacity in
>   Ampere-hours  (Ah).  Due to the unique charging characteristic of the
>   Li-Ion cells and batteries, charging  requires a dedicated charger
>   that can keep the cells and batteries within their specified voltage 
>   limits.  This charger may be a “smart” charger in some cases.  The
>   discharge of the cell depends  on the load used, but the end voltage
>   during discharge should not go below 2.5 V.  Typical end  of discharge
>   voltages for the batteries in different equipment has been 3.0 V/cell.
>   Internal  resistance for the Li-Ion cells varies from 9 to 120 mΩ for
>   small (1 to 3 Ah) cells to about 0.8  mΩ for large (190 Ah) cells

this the quote from the NASA document called [Guidelines on Lithium-ion Battery Use in Space 
Applications](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20090023862_2009023573.pdf)